# MATCH ... AGAINST doesn't come up with exact results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search

I'm working for the first time with MATCH...AGAINST in php sql but there is one bothering me and I can't figure out how to fix it. This is my code:

```
SELECT * FROM m_artist WHERE match(artist_name) against('". $_POST['article_content'] ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

And this is `$_POST['article_content']:`

```
Wildstylez Brothers Yeah Frontliner Waveliner
```

Now my output should be: Wildstylez, Frontliner and Waveliner cause that's in my database. And I do but besides that I also get the Vodka Brothers, 2 Brothers of Hardstyle and more cause of the word brothers. How do I fix that SQL only selects the literal match?

Comment: Literal match has a more precise definition than what you use.

Comment: @Mihai So what should I use?

Comment: It`s not clear at all what you want.FULL TEXT search searches for one of those words so it works...

Comment: I only want to find Wildstylez, Frontliner and Waveliner because they are in the database. Since I used the word brothers it also finds Vodka Brothers but that's not what I want. Question is how to change the query to make it work @Mihai

Comment: You could start by clarifying which database you are using. [tag:sql] on it's own doesn't help that much. Are you suing [tag:mysql]?

Comment: Yes I'm using MySQL @TheConstructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full-text search actually is a quite misleading name: you can search the full text by your query (like google does) but it won't guarantee you, that the full text equals your query.

So, according to [documentation on Boolean Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html) your input `Wildstylez Brothers Yeah Frontliner Waveliner` is interpreted as `artist_name` contains (at least) one of `Wildstylez`, `Brothers`, `Yeah`, `Frontliner` and `Waveliner` as word. This is why you get e.g. `the Vodka Brothers`, which contains `Brothers`. For google-like purposes this is just what you want, as you want to get details on something you only know part of as in show me articles on `music`.

You probably want to use

```
artist_name LIKE '%name_part1%' OR artist_name LIKE '%name_part2%' ...
```

or

```
artist_name IN ('exact_name1', 'exact_name2', ...)
```

simpliest case would be doing something like

```
$names = explode(' ', $_POST['article_content']);
$name_searches = array_map(function($a) {return 'artist_name = \''.mysql_real_escape_string($a).'\'';}, $names);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM m_artist WHERE ".implode(" OR ", $name_searches);
```

but you would loose the ability to find `2 Brothers of Hardstyle` as the name itself contains a space.

Another approach can be to prefix all words by '+' and stick to `MATCH() AGAINST()` and you will find only artists which include every word given.

Please provide more context if this is not what you are looking for.